# Python strings in RAM

Tags: python, unicode

How are string variables saved in the RAM?

for example: `foo = 'abcÇ¶'` and `s = u'abc\u2119'`.

The strings contains UNICODE characters, so should it be and how is it encoded before stored in memory?

Comment: That would depend on the specific Python implementation.

Comment: Since [PEP 393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/), the internal representation of unicode text is variable. It used to be UCS-4 by default (there was an flag to use UCS-2 instead if I'm not mistaken). Now it uses an array of elements the same size of the widest Unicode character in the string.

Comment: If the answer does indeed answer your question, please accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking about CPython, the standard Python implementation.

The Unicode string representation was changed beginning with [Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-393-flexible-string-representation) as described in [PEP 0393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/). Since then, strings use the same number of bytes for all characters, either 1, 2 or 4, choosing the smallest possible for each string depending on its contents. The specific encodings used are:

- 1 byte per char: Latin-1
- 2 bytes per char: UCS-2
- 4 bytes per char: UCS-4

Before version 3.3, the Unicode string representation depended on the system, and was usually either UTF-16, UCS-4 or UCS-2, to the best of my understanding. See the above-mentioned [PEP 0393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/) and its references for more details.